# Strange number validation in jQueryValidate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a text field like this :

```
$("#someForm").validate({
    rules: {
        someNumber: {
            number: true
        }
    }
});
```

As expected, validation fails for inputs like `4,12` or `3,1415`.

However, it validates the following input `3,141`.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `number` rule is looking for a ["valid decimal number"](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/).

> As expected, validation fails for inputs like 4,12 or 3,1415.
>
> However, it validates the following input 3,141.  Why?

Because `3,141` represents *"three thousand, one hundred and forty one"*.

The comma is called a "thousands separator" and is valid in this position...

> In European languages, large numbers are read in groups of thousands and the delimiter (which occurs every three digits when it is used) may be called a "thousands separator"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping

---

To ignore commas, periods, minus signs, and anything other than digits, use [the `digits` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/) instead...

> Makes the element require digits only

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/hv0pw8ks/](http://jsfiddle.net/hv0pw8ks/)